# Appending a number to sublists while also when the input is only a list

Tags: python, sage

I am running into some errors depending on the input.
The code runs if the input is a list of lists, but it does not run if the input is just a list.

```py
def someFunction(input):
    output = [i + [0] for i in input]
    print output
someFunction([[1,2],[2,1]]) #list of lists runs
someFunction([[1,2]]) #list of lists with only one sublist runs
someFunction([1,2]) #list does not run
```

Is there a way to make the code run with a list as input?

Comment: Maybe you could add which inputs cause errors and which do not, and what you expect the output to look like. It looks like you are trying to use `+` between a scalar and a list, where if `input` is a simple list, then `i` will be scalar, while `[0]` is a list. That's why you get an error, which probably starts with `ypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +:`

Comment: you should not name a variable as `input` since it's a built-in method, use something like `input_value` instead.

Comment: @Tiendung that is definitely good advice but not the reason he is having a problem.

Comment: @Deepstop yeah I know. that's why i just post it as a comment here.

@marble for a list of integer input, `i + [0]` might cause the problem since you can't sum an integer and a list.

Comment: @Tiendung i also tried to append the 0 and it gives the same problem. Deepstop, if i change the variable of 'input' to '*input' the code will work for the list, but will append a 0 to the list of list and not each sublist

Comment: @Deepstop the error you mentioned is the one i'm getting. I think I will just make two different functions specifying the different types of input needed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using Python V2.something, based on your print statement. You could try something like this, a list [1, 3, 5] would result in output [[1, 0], [3,0], [5,0]]

```
def someFunction(my_input):
    output = [i + [0] if type(i) == list else [i] + [0] for i in my_input]
    print output
```

If using Python 3, you want the print statement to look like

```
    print(output)
```

If you want the list [1, 3, 5] to result in [1, 3, 5, 0], then this would work well.

```
def someFunction(my_input):
    if all(type(i) == list for in in my_input)):
        print [i + [0] for i in my_input]
    elif any(type(i) == list for in in my_input)):
        print 'You cannot have both scalars and lists in the input list'
    else:
        print my_input + [0]
```

Comment: honestly, I'm not sure which version of python Sage uses. I think I did not specify clearly enough. If the list is [1, 3, 5], I want it to output [1, 3, 5, 0], considering the [1,3,5] as a list of one sublist. I think I will make two separate functions for two different types of input. Thanks for the explainations!

Comment: @marble no problem. If the print statement works without the parentheses, then you are using V2. I've added another approach that gives the result you want. I'm not sure what you would do with a list that contains both scalars and lists, so I just print a message.

Comment: Just as a comment, although the default for Sage is still Python 2, it will be switching to default v3 by the end of the calendar year (or so we hope).  You can already use it with v3 by compiling it yourself, on CoCalc, or possibly in other venues.